# Why insert is rolled back when validation triggered in bulk update

Tags: apex, validation-rule, insert, bulk, rollback

I have list of 2 records i try to update in bulk from object foo__c, this should trigger an insert of 2 records from the object zoo__c.

One of the updated foo records hits a validation rule (as expected) and the second one should proceed and create a zoo record, which seem to happen when looking at the logs- the zoo record reached the after insert trigger and got an id and exited the trigger without any errors or exceptions.

However, the zoo record doesn't exist when searching in Salesforce after the transaction completed, it seems to be rolled back, but there's no indication on that in the logs.

We tried to move the validation to code (addError) and also use Database.insert(x,false) and both didn't help, we got the same result.

Can anyone explain this behaviour and suggest a solution to successfully create the zoo record?

Comment: edit: I think if the trigger hits a validation rule when saving that gets treated like an error. Because Bulk Load processes records in chunks of up to 200 records at a time, if there is an error the whole chunk fails to save.

Comment: You do need to ensure the insert is done with `allOrNone` set `false` - you appear to mention this rather in passing, but it is essential. Also, as above, is this trigger-based "validation" or an actual validation rule? If it is trigger-based validation, this works as long as you use `addError` on the record or on one of the record's fields, but throwing an exception will cause what you are seeing.

Comment: Wait, are we talking about Bulk API?

Comment: 1. It's a validation rule not a trigger based 
2. This is not bulk api
3. We tried allOrNone=false it's still the same result